# Blackberry way to store audio and video into sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, video, blackberry, blob, blackberry-storm

I want to make a blackberry app. which will store audio and video files into the sqlite database.

Does blackberry have a special api for this? (special classes for byte[])

Can I store files into sqlite on blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sure can](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q10). Have a look at [using BLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_write) in version 3+. Why you'd want too instead of using links to the content, well, that's up to you and the particular application you're looking to create of course.

Here's a good development guide from RIM on [working with SQLite on the Blackberry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/index.jsp?name=SQLite+-+Development+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Java+Applications5.0+Beta&language=English&userType=21&category=Development+Guides&subCategory=) platform.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hate to resurrect a zombie thread, but how does one insert a blob into a table in blackberry?