# In Blackberry,How to Store image in Database?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I want to store Image into a SQLite Database in Blackberry.. so what i have to do?? I want to fetch images from server and then want to store in database.. I got images from server perfectly and store image as byte[] in database.. but i am not able to fetch it..
So plz help me...

Code edited into the question so it may be read:

```
try {
   Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT * FROM Image");
   st.prepare(); 
   Cursor c = st.getCursor();
   Row r;
   while(c.next()) {
      r = c.getRow();
      byte[] pic=r.getBlobBytes(0);
      st.close();
      EncodedImage _bmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(pic, 0, pic.length);
      BitmapField bmf=new BitmapField(_bmap.getBitmap());
      add(bmf);
   }
} catch ( Exception e ) {
   System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can store an image as a SQL BLOB.  [Take a look at this thread for a start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2343780/119114), and let us know if you still need help.

Comment: Ya ok sure..Thanx a lot 4 ur rep...

Comment: hey i insert image as array of bytes and it stored in db..bt when i fetch,it displaying nthng..

Comment: see my code..  try { Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT * FROM Image");
        
        st.prepare();
        Cursor c = st.getCursor(); 

        Row r;
        while(c.next()) {
            r = c.getRow();
         byte[] pic=r.getBlobBytes(0);
         
           st.close();
        
           EncodedImage _bmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(pic, 0, pic.length);
       BitmapField bmf=new BitmapField(_bmap.getBitmap());
       add(bmf);
        }

       
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {         
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: please **edit** your question and put any additional code in there, formatted. it's very hard to read in comments down here.  thanks!

Comment: Did that already nate ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't mention the name of the blob column, so I will call it `image_data`.  Something like this should work for insertion:

```
EncodedImage pic = getImage();
byte [] imageBytes = pic.getData();
Statement st = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO Image (image_data) values (?)");
st.prepare();
st.bind(1, imageBytes);
st.execute();
```

For retrieval, explicitly naming the column may help, as your current code assumes the blob is always the first column in the table schema.  Also, you shouldn't close the statement in the loop, as this will block reading anything after the first image:

```
Statement st = db.createStatement("SELECT image_data FROM Image");
st.prepare(); 
Cursor c = st.getCursor();
Row r;
while(c.next()) {
   r = c.getRow();
   byte[] pic=r.getBlobBytes(0);
   EncodedImage _bmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(pic, 0, pic.length);
   BitmapField bmf=new BitmapField(_bmap.getBitmap());
   add(bmf);
}
st.close();  // moved this line out of the loop
```

Comment: @ michael Hey if u have any idea regarding blackberry devices resolution then plz visit this link and help me.. Thanks in advance.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153613/blackberry-resolution